# Geometrical shapes with useful functions

Tags: matlab, geometry

Lets say I have an object which I want to enclose geometrically in 3D using a fixed number of planes, n. I then would want to ask my geometric representation things like: is point x inside my shape or outside?

Do I have to program this myself, or are there suitable MATLAB solutions already existent? I have seen that there are triangulations and boundaries in MATLAB. But they do not seem to have the function stated above (and use triangles, which I guess would also be ok).

So, what I am asking is: How would you represent an enclosing geometrically shape in 3D for an object and then be able to ask this shape things as volume and if a point lies outside or inside?

Comment: What you're describing is commonly known as a BSP Tree (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_space_partitioning).  I can't comment whether it's in MATLAB or not, but you should be able to easily add it.

Comment: If you want just to add inside mesh functionality then boundary representation of mesh (triangulation/polygonisation) is OK you can use Hit Test in 3D the same as in 2D and also not that hard to code it yourself. so the half planes implementation would be an overkill I think with too many other problems coming in ...